# How to omit directory name and blank lines when listing directory contents with PowerShell's Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide -AutoSize


    Directory: C:\Users\user



Contacts                                                 Cookies
Desktop                                                  Documents
Downloads                                                Favorites


PS C:\Users\user>
```

Is there a convenient way to omit the directory header as well as the 7 blank lines in the output?

Bonus points if the solution plays well with [DirColors](https://github.com/DHowett/DirColors).

Answer (score 1):

For a really simple example, I'd select for name:

```
PS> (Get-ChildItem).Name
.docker
.ssh
.vscode
3D Objects
Calibre Library
Code
Contacts
Documents
Downloads
EneticsNC
Favorites
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem with this solution is that it thwarts [DirColors](https://github.com/DHowett/DirColors).

Answer (score 1):

This allows for the use of `Format-WIde` and strips the leading & trailing blank lines:

```
(Get-ChildItem | Select name | Format-Wide | Out-String).Trim("$([char]0x0a+[char]0x0d)")
```

Output:

```
PS C:\...\keith>(gci | select name | format-wide | out-string).Trim("$([char]0x0a+[char]0x0d)")
Contacts                                     Desktop
Documents                                    Downloads
Favorites                                    Links
Music                                        OneDrive
Original 3D Content                          Pictures
Sandbox                                      Saved Games
Screenshots                                  Searches
Standalone Programs                          Videos
2002271222HotKeys.reg                        2002271230HotKeys.reg
5f7b5f1e01b83767.automaticDestinations-ms    A20200807.txt
adstest.txt                                  AllFolders-StandardDetails.reg
arrByte.xml                                  atesty.reg
audioprops.txt                               B20200807.txt
BadTableWithDups                             bytes2.txt
Documents2002271232HotKeys.reg               DTShortcut.ps1
dummy.ini                                    env.txt
File Explorer.lnk                            filelist.txt
file_ex1_ex2.ex3                             gci.txt
help.txt                                     hex.bin
hkcrlevel1.txt                               hkcrlevel2.txt
HKLMAllFoldersDetails.txt                    hotkeys.xml
junctions.txt                                list.txt
listtxt                                      mkdir.txt
names.txt                                    NoEmpties.xml
out.txt                                      out2.txt
out3.txt                                     outnum.txt
PicLibTVBytes.txt                            Profcopy.ps1
redirect.txt                                 RegCommandExamples.txt
reginihelp.txt                               Relative.lnk
sc.lnk                                       script.ps1
set-clipboard                                Settings.reg
sha256.txt                                   sha2562.txt
star.txt                                     test (2).txt
test.txt                                     transTest.txt
usf.txt                                      WithEmpties.xml
PS C:\...\keith>
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem with this solution is that it thwarts [DirColors](https://github.com/DHowett/DirColors).

Comment: Annoyingly, `Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide | Out-String` misaligns entries due to DirColors.

Comment: Never heard of DirColors. But reading the link, it clearly says it works with "default formatting" -- which is what your original question wanted to twart! Choose your windmills, Don!

Comment: DirColors tweaks the formatting of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects. Once we `select name`, we no longer have a FileInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `-Name` parameter with your command while using `Get-ChildItem`. Its ouput does not show directory name.

```
Get-ChildItem -name | Format-Wide -AutoSize -Force
```

**Note:** that I have also use `-Force` parameter of `Format-Wide`.

**Before**

[image: IMG:]

**After**

[image: IMG:]

Comment: have you tested that code? on my win1-, ps5.1 setup, it does NOT remove the header line NOR does it remove the unwanted blank lines in the output.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey See the image added on my answer. It shows the output of the command using Powershell 7.0.3.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey One thing i have noticed (you should also checked it) is that the teading and trailing blank lines are the result of `Format-Wide` not `Get-ChildItem -Name`

Comment: ah! i really misread your post. [*blush*] should i remove this set of my comments? [also, thanks for the output display. [*grin*]]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I don't know if you misread or not (unless you explain :). I think you should not delete your comments, until I know if I at least understood (or came close to understand) your question, or if my answer is way of the mark. Leaving your comment might help others to come up with better answers.

Comment: thank you ... i shall leave them up! [*grin*]